# Ubuntu 17.10 wireless connection extremely slows down all the devices connected to the same router but normal in another router

Tags: networking, internet, 17.10, dns, router

My computer is Surface Pro 4. The router leading slow wireless connection was provided by the ISP, so it cannot be replaced. The normal one is a tomato-based router and an old one bought years ago with which I used for VPN connection.

Here is the upgrading rate, which I have a 2009 Thinkpad (Ubuntu 16.04) with the same source and it can reach about 3,000 kB/s.

```
10% [37 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 5,648 kB/6,148 kB 92%]   3,534 B/s 1d 15h 33min 5s
```

**N.B.** Averagely, the rate is about 20~30 kB/s. Because now I connected to the VPN router, the upgrading rate is slow. However, I can visit all the website within a relatively normal time and all the websites are accessible now without refreshing.

I almost tried all the method I googled and on 'askbuntu'.It seems a DNS problem, as usually a new website cannot be connected or at least I should refresh it one time.

```
    $ ls -la /etc/resolv.conf
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 32 1月  10 16:57 /etc/resolv.conf -> 
    /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf

    $ sudo vim /etc/resolv.conf
    nameserver 192.168.1.1
    # or if I connected to another WIFI (normal one), the content of the file is
    # nameserver 192.168.10.1
```

I already purged the unbound because it didn't work.

Also, I tried this way someone provided.

```
    $ sudo gedit /etc/moddprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
    add "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1" in the file
```

It didn't work too.

Is there anyone know how to fix this instead of buying a new router. Any help will be appreciated.

**P.S.** Once this computer connected to the router, it seems the whole netwrok break down. All my other devices like phone suffers slow network rate. Once I shutdown this computer the network recoverd.